# Passbook Passes expiring after a day

Tags: passbook, wallet, passkit

Generating a passbook file using `passkit4j` with relevance date of today and no expiration date.
However, the pass in apple wallet seems to expire after a day.

Question:

1. How can I make pass with no expiration date
2. What is relevance date  ?

Tried changing `expiration date` to multiple different values but doesnt seem to work

Comment: What type of pass is it?

Comment: @TomasMcGuinness A store card, like a gift card

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but according to Apple's documents, Relevance Date has no meaning for store cards.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html

Check Table 4-2

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that some versions of iOS uses the `relevantDate` as expiration date for a pass.

Otherwise use the `expirationDate` property